# Searching numpy array for element values and storing location

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array which represents the adjacency of faces in a 3D model. In general the nth row and column represent the nth face of the model. If a 1 is located in the upper right triangle of the matrix, it represents a convex connection between two faces. If a 1 is located in the lower left triangle, it represents a concave connection.

For example in the matrix below, there are convex connections between faces 1 and 2, 1 and 3, 2 and 3 and so on.

```
       1   2   3   4   5   6

1   [[ 0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
2    [ 0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
3    [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
4    [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
5    [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
6    [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Id like to be able to record how many concave and convex connections each face has.

i.e. Face 1 has: 0 concave and 2 convex connections

Possibly even record which faces they are connected to.

i.e. Face 1 has: 0 concave and 2 convex (2, 3) connections

So far I have tried using `np.nonzero()` to return the indices of the 1's. However this returns the indices in a format which doesn't seem to be very easy to work with (a separate array for the row and column indices:

```
(array([ 0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  3]), array([ 1,  2,  2,  3,  4,  5, 
 4]))
```

Can anyone help me with an easier way to carry out this task? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
import numpy as np


a=np.matrix([[0,1,1,0,0,0],
[ 0,0,1,1,1,1],
[ 0,0,0,0,0,0],
[ 0,0,0,0,1,0],
[ 0,0,0,0,0,0],
[ 0,0,0,0,0,0]]).astype(float)

concave={}
convex={}
for i,j in zip(np.nonzero(a)[0]+1,np.nonzero(a)[1]+1):
if j > i :
    if i not in convex.keys():
        convex[i]=[]
    if j not in convex.keys():
        convex[j]=[]
    convex[i].append(j)
    convex[j].append(i)
else :
    if i not in concave.keys():
        concave[i]=[]
    if j not in concave.keys():
        concave[j]=[]
    concave[i].append(j)
    concave[j].append(i)

print 'concave relations : {} and number of relations is {}'.format(concave,sum(len(v) for v in concave.values()))

print 'convex relations : {} and number of relations is {}'.format(convex,sum(len(v) for v in convex.values()))
```

gives the result :

> concave relations : {} and number of relations is 0
>
> convex relations : {1: [2, 3], 2: [1, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3: [1, 2], 4: [2, 5], 5: [2, 4], 6: [2]} and number of relations is 14

where the dictionary key is the name of the face and key values are it's connections.

Logic is :

for every **non-zero** pair **(i,j)**

- if i>j then j is the concave connection of face i & i is the concave connection of face j
- if j>i then j is the convex connection of face i & i is the convex connection of face j

Comment: Wow, thanks Pratik that is a fantastic solution. However, the code you have written only counts the elements by row.. so for example Face 5 has no convex connections (in your result you have written). If you look at the columns, Face 5 has concave relations with 2 and 4. I know this is already shown in `2: [3, 4, 5, 6], 4: [5]`, but how can I get this code to count elements column wise as well? So for example concave connections would then be `{1: [2, 3], 2: [3, 4, 5, 6], 3: [1, 2], 4: [2, 5], 5: [2, 4], 6: [2]}`  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @haagn  I can't follow, in the question you have mentioned that face 1 has **0 concave** relations now you say concave relations should be {1: [2, 3], 2: [3, 4, 5, 6], 3: [1, 2], 4: [2, 5], 5: [2, 4], 6: [2]}. Also, how does 5 have **concave** relations with 2 and 4. Also, how does 5 have **concave** relations with 2 and 4

Comment: Sorry I meant **convex**. I have been writing both of these so much recently I type them out wrong sometimes haha

Comment: @haagn, that mistake got me wondering for like 30 mins. Anyways I have updated the answer have a look

Comment: Im very sorry! Yeah I tested it out and it works perfectly, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0],
              [0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1],
              [0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
              [0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0],
              [0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
              [0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])

convex = np.triu(A, 1)  # upper triangle
concave = np.tril(A, -1)  # lower triangle

convex_indices = list(zip(np.nonzero(convex)[0] + 1, np.nonzero(convex)[1] + 1))
concave_indices = list(zip(np.nonzero(concave)[0] + 1, np.nonzero(concave)[1] + 1))

num_convex = len(convex_indices)
num_concave = len(concave_indices)

print('There are {} convex connections between faces: {}'.format(num_convex, ', '.join(str(e) for e in convex_indices)))
print('There are {} concave connections between faces: {}'.format(num_concave, ', '.join(str(e) for e in concave_indices)))

# will print:
# There are 7 convex connections between faces: (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (4, 5)
# There are 0 concave connections between faces:
```